# Websocket base64, binarytype

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, websocket, network-programming

I'm very confused. I'm trying to understand how Websockets work and have build a server in node.js and a client side.
What I couldn't understand is, how Websocket sends data.
Is the data base64 encoded before sending from client (browser) ?
How is 'binarytype' working ? Only for receiving ?

And do I have to implement these on server, too ?
Do I need a 'binarytype' option on server side ?

When do I need blob and arraybuffer ? Depending on small and big data ?
What is if get get videos and audio files ?

I had a look on how pictures should be sent on web and I found 
very often the solution, that the picture is base64 encoded and send after that.
But if Websocket API in Browser already encode binary files to base64, I wouldn't have to do this..

Sorry, I'm very confused and hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), especially [5. Data Framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5), and you can find answers there.

*In the WebSocket Protocol, data is transmitted using a sequence of **frames*** (and not base64-encoded). Frame types defined in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) are as follows.

1. Continuation Frame (opcode = 0x0)
2. **Text** Frame (opcode = 0x1)
3. **Binary** Frame (opcode = 0x2)
4. Close Frame (opcode = 0x8)
5. Ping Frame (opcode = 0x9)
6. Pong Frame (opcode = 0xA)

Decent WebSocket libraries (both client-side ones and server-side ones) can handle all of these frames and provide functions/methods to send/receive them. So, you don't have to worry about how data are encoded regardless of whether data are text or binary (unless you choice a bad WebSocket library).

Note that both clients and servers can send/receive both text frames and binary frames.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm writing my own libray and want to understand how this works. I know that frames are sended, but how gets the data into that frame ? What happens there in encoding ?

Comment: See the implementation of [WebSocketOutputStream.write(WebSocketFrame)](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/neovisionaries/ws/client/WebSocketOutputStream.java#L41) in [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client), and you can understand how data are packed into frames. Note that the payload part must be masked when frames are sent from client to server and must not be in the opposite direction. See RFC 6455 [5.3. Client-to-Server Masking](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.3) for details.

Comment: I understand now how Data is sended. But it was not what i was looking for. Can you please explain for what the 'binarytype' option is ? Does the client browser api change the entity of incoming message when it is set to 'blob' and the incoming message contains an arraybuffer ? or is it just a wish, how it is (the incoming message) preferred ? How can the server know, what to what the 'binarytype' option is set on client side in browser ?

Comment: `binaryType` is an attribute to indicate which JavaScript class ([Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) or [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer)) you want to use when handling binary messages. For example, if `binaryType` is `arraybuffer`, a received binary message is converted to an `ArrayBuffer` object and you will see it in `onmessage()` callback. See [MDN WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket). Regardless of what the value of `binaryType` is, binary frames are sent as binary frames.

Comment: I had a look at wireshark and can now say, that binary messages are hex dumps from the sended binary and array buffers the hex view of the buffers content.And I understood, that binarytype is only a clientside browser option and not provided for the server side, is that correct? What I've not tested is, what happens if the binarytype is set to blob and the server sends a arraybuffer and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Websockets can transmit text and binary data. WebSocket binary data comes in two shapes: blobs and array buffers.

```
ws.binaryType = "blob";
// or
ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
```

So you don't need to transform binary to text and text to binary to do transmission. You can use binary directly.

The problems you are probably referring to (e.g binary to base64) arose out of the fact that for a long time browsers didn't handle binary well in combination with JavaScript so you needed to shuffle text around instead, to bypass the limitations. This has improved in modern browsers (although I don't know the exact support in each major browser).

Have a look at this for more details: [Processing Binary Protocols with Client-Side JavaScript](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/02/06/parsing-binary-protocol-data-javascript-typedarrays-blobs/)

Regarding the server side, yes, you also need to handle binary data. If the client is expecting binary the server should send binary. Now, I'm not all that familiar with Node.js but a quick search turns up this package that looks promising: http://binaryjs.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I have to implement a 'binarytype' option for the server ? As I understood, 'binarytype' option is only for the client side as feedback, to handle incoming messages. And how can I check on server side, which 'binarytype' is wanted from client ?